# insert data into table with foreign keys php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has 1 primary and 2 foreign keys, i dont think i am inserting them correctly. when i try and do it on phpmyadmin i have the options to pick [dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNB1x.png) thats why i dont think i can use the insert code below?

I tried to just insert into the seat_id only and that didnt work. Then i tried to get the information and insert it, that also didnt work.

It says it submitted to php but it actually didnt.

this is output code

```
    You are currently accessing database; your username is: admin.
    admin@airways.com
    5A
    5B
    5C
    successfully taken seat.
    Back to seating.
```

[image: relations table]

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
    include_once 'includes/functions.php';
    sec_session_start();


    if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'accessing';
} else {
    $logged = 'not accessing';
}
                $username = $_SESSION['username'];
                echo  '<p>You are currently '.$logged. ' database; your username is: '.$username. '.</p><br>';

                $getemail = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT email FROM members WHERE username = '$username' ");
                $email = '';
                while($gear = mysqli_fetch_array( $getemail )) {
                    echo $gear['email'];
                    $email = $gear['email'];
                } 

                echo $gear."<br>";


    if(isset($_POST['seatme'])){
                print 'initiate POST<br>';

        if(!empty($_POST['flight'])){
            print 'SEATME exists <br>';

            foreach($_POST['flight'] as $key=>$selected){
                echo $selected."<br>";

if ( $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO seating (flight_id, email, seat_id) VALUES ('1', '".$username."', '".$selected."')",  MYSQLI_USE_RESULT))
    {
    print 'Insert OK<br>';
    }else{
    print 'something wrong here<br>';
    }

?>
```

---

```
        You are currently accessing database; your username is: admin.


admin@airways.com
initiate POST
SEATME exists 
9A
something wrong here
Array
(
    [flight] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9A
            [1] => 9B
            [2] => 9C
        )

    [seatme] => Submit
)
```

---

[Here is a picture of what that looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CTDl.png)

```
                    <div class="plane">
  <div class="cockpit" >
    <h1>Please select a seat</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="exit exit--front fuselage text-center">
  </div>
  <form action="flightselect.php" method="post" name="form"> 
  <ol class="cabin fuselage">
    <li class="row row--1" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1A" value="1A" />
          <label for="1A">1A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1B" value="1B" />
          <label for="1B">1B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1C" value="1C" />
          <label for="1C">1C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1D" value="1D" />
          <label for="1D">1D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1E" value="1E" />
          <label for="1E">1E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1F" value="1F" />
          <label for="1F">1F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--2" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2A" value="2A" />
          <label for="2A">2A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2B" value="2B" />
          <label for="2B">2B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2C" value="2C" />
          <label for="2C">2C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2D" value="2D" />
          <label for="2D">2D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2E" value="2E" />
          <label for="2E">2E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2F" value="2F" />
          <label for="2F">2F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--3" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3A" value="3A" />
          <label for="3A">3A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3B" value="3B" />
          <label for="3B">3B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3C" value="3C" />
          <label for="3C">3C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3D" value="3D" />
          <label for="3D">3D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3E" value="3E" />
          <label for="3E">3E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3F" value="3F" />
          <label for="3F">3F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--4" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4A" value="4A" />
          <label for="4A">4A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4B" value="4B" />
          <label for="4B">4B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4C" value="4C" />
          <label for="4C">4C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4D" value="4D" />
          <label for="4D">4D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4E" value="4E" />
          <label for="4E">4E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4F" value="4F" />
          <label for="4F">4F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--5" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5A" value="5A" />
          <label for="5A">5A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5B" value="5B" />
          <label for="5B">5B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5C" value="5C" />
          <label for="5C">5C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5D" value="5D" />
          <label for="5D">5D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5E" value="5E" />
          <label for="5E">5E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5F" value="5F" />
          <label for="5F">5F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--6" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6A" value="6A" />
          <label for="6A">6A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6B" value="6B" />
          <label for="6B">6B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6C" value="6C" />
          <label for="6C">6C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6D" value="6D" />
          <label for="6D">6D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6E" value="6E" />
          <label for="6E">6E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6F" value="6F" />
          <label for="6F">6F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--7" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7A" value="7A" />
          <label for="7A">7A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7B" value="7B" />
          <label for="7B">7B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7C" value="7C" />
          <label for="7C">7C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7D" value="7D" />
          <label for="7D">7D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7E" value="7E" />
          <label for="7E">7E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7F" value="7F" />
          <label for="7F">7F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--8" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8A" value="8A" />
          <label for="8A">8A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8B" value="8B" />
          <label for="8B">8B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8C" value="8C" />
          <label for="8C">8C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8D" value="8D" />
          <label for="8D">8D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8E" value="8E" />
          <label for="8E">8E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8F" value="8F" />
          <label for="8F">8F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--9" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9A" value="9A" />
          <label for="9A">9A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9B" value="9B" />
          <label for="9B">9B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9C" value="9C" />
          <label for="9C">9C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9D" value="9D" />
          <label for="9D">9D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9E" value="9E" />
          <label for="9E">9E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9F" value="9F" />
          <label for="9F">9F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--10" style="padding-left: 4%";>
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10A" value="10A" />
          <label for="10A">10A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10B" value="10B" />
          <label for="10B">10B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10C" value="10C" />
          <label for="10C">10C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10D" value="10D" />
          <label for="10D">10D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10E" value="10E" />
          <label for="10E">10E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10F" value="10F" />
          <label for="10F">10F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <div class="exit exit--back fuselage">    
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="seatme" value="Submit" style="font-weight: bold;">
</form>
```

Comment: At first look at your code, it seems you have a big mistake: $_POST['flight'] is not an Array to use foreach statement... it is just a variable... you can check by debugging $_POST... How to debug? Put on top of page the following: print '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); die; and run the code

Comment: okay, i updated my code to reflect more what was going on in my code. I am able to print all my variables. it wont send it to sql though.

Comment: it still the same: *foreach($_POST['flight'] as $key=>$selected)* seems to be wrong... $_POST['flight'] - this is not an array of multiple IDs

Comment: run this: **print '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); die;** and post bellow to your answer than it will be clear what is wrong

Comment: Array
(
    [flight] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2A
            [1] => 2B
            [2] => 2C
            [3] => 3E
            [4] => 4E
        )

    [seatme] => Submit
)

Comment: First of all, the Many to Many relation between members and flights is not established well through the junction table seatings. Try to stick to convention i.e seatings table should be renamed to `flight_members` and that table should have `flight_id`  and `member_id` fields.

Comment: have a look here:   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO seating (flight_id, email, seat_id) VALUES ('1', '".$username."', '".$selected."')";

Answer (score 0):

I will use this space because I can show code rather give a comment. 
I will delete  this answer later. Try to debug Step By step as I suggest bellow. 
Otherwise it seems that it should work your code.

```
if(isset($_POST['seatme'])){
    print 'SEATME exists <br>;
    if(!empty($_POST['flight'])){
        print 'FLIGHT exists <br>';
            foreach($_POST['flight'] as $key=>$selected){
             //    echo $selected."<br>";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO seating (flight_id, email, seat_id) VALUES ('1', '".$username."', '".$selected."')";
            $resut=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die('ERROR is here: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli)); // it should work displaying error
            }

    }else{
        echo "<font color='red'>Please select seats .</font><br/>";
        }

echo "<font color='green'>successfully taken seat.";
echo "<br/><a href='user.php'>Back to seating.</a>";
    }else{
        echo "<font color='red'>Please select seats .</font><br/>";
        }
```

Comment: i did what u said it seems in the $result the inserting isnt working. i updated the code above in my question to reflect

Comment: I have modified a bit code above, hope it will help you to discover the problem...